# Single-pole IIR low-pass filter - which is the correct formula for the decay coefficient?

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response

A single-pole IIR low-pass filter can be defined in discrete time as `y += a * (x - y)`, where `y` is the output sample, `x` is the input sample and `a` is the decay coefficient.

However, the definition of `a` varies.
On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Simple_infinite_impulse_response_filter), it's defined as `2πfc/(2πfc+1)` (where `fc` is the cutoff frequency).

But [here](https://tomroelandts.com/articles/low-pass-single-pole-iir-filter), `a` is defined as follows: `1 - e^-2πfc`.

Their graphs look similar, but which one is more accurate?

The blue graph is the Wikipedia formula, the green is the second one, `fc` is the x-axis.
[image: GeoGebra graph]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exponential weighted moving average time constant](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/exponential-weighted-moving-average-time-constant)

Comment: I disagree. There are two conflicting formulas given, but the question you linked covers how one of them can be derived. Edit: However, there's a note that the formulas are only an approximation, which might imply that both of those are usable.

Comment: See my answer below, both are indeed approximations derived from the corresponding analog filter, and only one of them is useful, provided that the cut-off frequency is much smaller than Nyquist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The given single-pole IIR filter is also called [exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) filter, and it is defined by the following difference equation:

$$y[n]=\alpha x[n]+(1-\alpha)y[n-1],\qquad 0<\alpha<1\tag{1}$$

Its transfer function is

$$H(z)=\frac{\alpha}{1-(1-\alpha)z^{-1}}\tag{2}$$

The exact formula for the required value of $\alpha$ that results in a desired $3\;\textrm{dB}$ cut-off frequency $\omega_c$ was derived in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/28314/4298):

$$\alpha=-y+\sqrt{y^2+2y},\qquad y=1-\cos(\omega_c)\tag{3}$$

Even though it should be easy enough to compute $\alpha$ from $(3)$, there are several approximative formulas floating around the internet. One of them is

$$\alpha\approx 1-e^{-\omega_c}\tag{4}$$

In [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/28314/4298) I've explained how this formula is derived (namely, via the impulse invariant transformation of the corresponding continuous-time low pass filter). [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34974/4298) compares the approximation $(4)$ with the exact formula, and it is shown that $(4)$ is only useful for relatively small cut-off frequencies (of course, small compared to the sampling frequency).

In the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Simple_infinite_impulse_response_filter) given in the question, there is yet another approximative formula:

$$\alpha\approx\frac{\omega_c}{1+\omega_c}\tag{5}$$

[Note that in all formulas of this answer $\omega_c$ is normalized by the sampling frequency.] This approximation is also derived from discretizing the corresponding analog transfer function, this time not via the impulse invariant method, but by replacing the derivative by a backward difference:

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}{\huge |}_{t=nT}\approx\frac{y(nT)-y((n-1)T)}{T}\tag{6}$$

This is equivalent to replacing $s$ by $(1-z^{-1})/T$ in the continuous-time transfer function

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{1+s\tau}\tag{7}$$

which results in

$$H(z)=\frac{1}{1+(1-z^{-1})\tau/T}=\frac{\frac{1}{1+\tau/T}}{1-\frac{\tau/T}{1+\tau/T}z^{-1}}\tag{8}$$

Comparing $(8)$ to $(2)$ we see that

$$\alpha=\frac{1}{1+\tau/T}\tag{9}$$

Since the (continuous-time) $3\;\textrm{dB}$ cut-off frequency is $\Omega_c=1/\tau$, we obtain from $(9)$

$$\alpha=\frac{\Omega_cT}{1+\Omega_cT}\tag{10}$$

Equating the discrete-time cut-off frequency $\omega_c$ with $\Omega_cT$ in $(10)$ gives the approximation $(5)$.

The figure below shows the actually achieved cut-off frequency for a given desired cut-off frequency for the two approximations $(4)$ and $(5)$. Clearly, both approximations become useless for larger cut-off frequencies, and I would suggest that approximation $(5)$ is generally useless.

[image]

Comment: How about this approximation (sorry, just in coefficient format ): `x = 1.0/(fs*T);            % fs in Hz, T in μs  
a0 = 1.0;  
a1 = -(1 + x + 0.5 * x^2); % Taylor approx  
b0 = a0 + a1; % gain  
b1 = 0.0;`

Comment: @MattL. Do you know the source of these approximations which are "floating around the internet"? Is there a paper or textbook which covers these? I imagine they may be useful because they may be simpler to implement in hardware?

Comment: @Ralph: I don't know the original source of those approximations. I also don't think that they are very useful. Eq. (4) is not very easy to implement, and Eq. (5) is such a bad approximation that it is useless in most situations.

Comment: it's not that the alpha-from-tau formula is an approximation, it's that the relationship between $\tau$ and $w_c$ is an approximation. If we define the time constant $\tau$ as the time it takes for the filter's step function to converge to within $\frac 1 e$, then the given formula $\alpha = 1 - e^{-\frac 1 \tau}$ is exact. This is often a useful definition of $\tau$ in a moving-average context, where you're more concerned with convergence time than frequency response.

Comment: In your final cutoff graph, does 1 correspond to 2pi (normalized frequency) or pi (Nyquist)?

Answer (score 2):

Matt L.’s exact answer in equation (3) is correct.  But here is a simpler “exact” solution:

= 2 / (  + 1 ),         = tan(  / 2 )         (11)

This is computationally more robust.  Eq (3) could lead to small errors depending on the resolution of your floating-point math.

Comment: This formula disagrees with (3).